# Number Theory: Prove that $m | \phi(a^m - 1)$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, divisibility, totient-function

> $a$ and $m$ are natural numbers and $a>1$. Prove that $m | \phi(a^m -
>  1)$.

Any hints how can I prove this statement?

Comment: do you heart about Lehmer Conjecture ?, try to let a=2 , it is the only  part for L.Conjecture  which it is proved

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/594233/prove-that-n-divides-phian-1-where-a-n-are-positive-integer-without OR   https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/774814/prove-that-n-divides-phian-1-where-phi-is-eulers-phi-function

Comment: The goal of this question is to show that m is prime iff m | phi(a^m-1) , and this happen if a^m-1 is prime , just we look for a=2 .

Comment: @zeraouliarafik [Lehmer's Totient Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lehmer%27s_totient_problem) asks whether there is any composite number $n$ such that Euler's totient function $φ(n)$ divides $n − 1$.

Comment: it could be proved easily for any number $m=(p_1-1)^{e_1} (p_2-1)^{e_2} \cdots $ where $p_i$ are prime numbers (not necessarily in order).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From $\gcd(a,a^m-1)=1$ [we have](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem) 
$$a^{\varphi(a^m-1)}\equiv 1 \pmod{a^m-1}$$
also 
$$a^{m}\equiv 1 \pmod{a^m-1}$$
If we assume $\varphi(a^m-1)=mq+r, 0<r<m$ then
$$a^{\varphi(a^m-1)}\equiv a^{mq+r} \equiv (a^m)^qa^r \equiv (1)^qa^r \equiv  a^r\equiv 1 \pmod{a^m-1}$$
which is a contradiction (because of $0<r<m$), so $r=0$.

Comment: I think there is no such contradiction. 2 ^ 3 ≡ 1 mod 7

Comment: 2^6 ≡ 1 mod 7 here

Comment: @EsposaDoYoongi which part do you mean? The contradiction is from $0<r<m$ we have $a^r -1 < a^m -1$ and $a^m -1 \mid a^r -1$, i.e. a greater number divides a smaller one.

Comment: Now I understand! Thank you!